# ExtJS 3.4 - How to "grey" the emptyText in DateField

Tags: extjs3

I encountered a problem in showing a datefield `emptyText` `("YYY-MM-DD")` in grey color instead of black color.

Here is my code.

Style

```
.emptyText {
    color: grey;
}
```

Script

```js
items : 
[ 
   {
    fieldLabel : "Create Date",
    xtype : 'compositefield',
    items : 
    [
        {
            xtype : "datefield",
            width : 110, 
            format: 'Y-m-d', 
            emptyText: "YYYY-MM-DD",
            emptyClass:"emptyText"
        },
        {
            xtype:"label", 
            width:20, 
            text: "to", 
            style:fieldLabelStyle2
        },
        {
            xtype : "datefield",
            width : 110,
            format: 'Y-m-d', 
            emptyText: "YYYY-MM-DD",
            emptyClass:"emptyText"
        } 
    ]
    }
]
```

I have also tried to include the html tag with style in emptyText, but the html tag is treated as plain text. It is set as follows

```
emptyText: '<span style="color:grey">YYYY-MM-DD</span>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ExtJS 3.x you can override the css class:

```
.x-form-empty-field {
    color: gray;
}
```

For ExtJS 4.x there is a property [emptyCls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-emptyCls).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have also tried this before, but still not work. However, I found that it is worked for font-weight:bold, but not worked for color. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try with gray or "grey"?